# The difference between returning by reference and a pointer in a const function

Tags: c++, class, constants

I'm investigating some C++ code, and I'd like to know why this code doesn't compile:

```cpp
class A {
    int K;
    const int* f(const int* k) const {
        return *k;
    }
};
```

and this code does compile:

```cpp
class A {
    int K;
    const int* f(const int* k) const {
        return &K;
    }
};
```

I dont understand what the difference is because I'm trying to return a `const` in the first one as well.

Is `&K` const because it is an address?

Comment: `*k` has type `const int`, but your function claims to return a `const int*`. You cannot convert a `const int` to a `const int*`. One is a pointer, the other isn't. Is that intended or a typo in the question?

Comment: first: you are working with 2 different "k" in the two examples

Comment: @Berto99 it's intented

Comment: @walnut, can you please tell me what is the type of &K? (capital)
Does &K type is const int *? if yes, can you please explain why?

Comment: @razlevy `&K` has type `const int*`. It is not clear to me what your question is. The error has nothing to do with `const`. The error you are getting is because pointers and non-pointers cannot be converted to one another implicitly. And nothing here is "*returning by ref*" either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer can hold the memory address of an object. Now, since your function `const int* f(const int* k) const` returns a `const` pointer to an `int`, that means you have to return to it either a `const` pointer to an `int` or the memory address of an `int`.

In your first code, you dereference your pointer and return it to the function, which means you're returning a value. This doesn't work by the above argument.

Your 2nd code, however, compiles since you return to `f` an address of an object (in your case the memory address of the integer `int K`).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're dereferencing `const int* k` pointer which means you're trying to return an `int` value whereas function `const int* f(const int* k) const` expects to return pointer `const int*`.

In the second case you're using & which returns an address of your int K class member and because `const int* f(const int* k) const` function expect that the return type will be pointer to `const int*` it does compile without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confused by the syntax here. Despite appearances, operator `*` returns a reference, while operator `&` returns a pointer. For example:

```
int k0 = 0;    // declare a regular int variable
int* k1 = &k0; // declare a pointer to int and assign the address of k0 to it
int& k2 = *k1; // declare a reference to int and make it refer to the value pointed by k1
```

So as you can see the meanings of `&` and `*` is sort of switched when used in an expression rather that in type declaration.